# remove double quotes from json encoded array

Tags: php, json

```
   $SQL = "SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mst_sim_data' 
            AND COLUMN_NAME = 'status'";
   $result = mysql_query($SQL);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   $enumList = explode(",", str_replace("'", '', substr($row['COLUMN_TYPE'], 5,     (strlen($row['COLUMN_TYPE'])-6))));

    foreach ($enumList as $key => $value) {
        $list["'$value'"] = $value;
    }       
    return json_encode($list);
```

This returns following json string.

```
Object {'INSTOCK': "INSTOCK", 'ISSUED': "ISSUED", 'SOLDOUT': "SOLDOUT"}
```

But I need to replace single quotes over double quotes and it should be like this,

```
'INSTOCK': 'INSTOCK', 'ISSUED': 'ISSUED', 'SOLDOUT': 'SOLDOUT'}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `str_replace('"', "'", $mystring)`?

Comment: str_replace not works

Answer (score 2):

Is the goal to break JSON output? JSON strings and properties *must* use `"` as the quote.

I believe the problem is two fold

1. `$list["'$value'"] = $value;` should be `$list["$value"] = $value;` and
2. the `"`s should be *left* alone

---

If you *do* wish to mangle the quotes (which means the result is *not* JSON), then use the *result of*

```
str_replace('"', "'", json_encode($list, JSON_HEX_APOS))
```

Note the JSON_HEX_APOS flag, to prevent this gross hack from mutilating any JSON-string embedded `'` characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQL = "SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mst_sim_data' 
            AND COLUMN_NAME = 'status'";
   $result = mysql_query($SQL);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   $enumList = explode(",", str_replace("'", '', substr($row['COLUMN_TYPE'], 5,     (strlen($row['COLUMN_TYPE'])-6))));

    foreach ($enumList as $key => $value) {
        $list["$value"] = $value;
    }       
    return str_replace('"',"'",json_encode($list));
```

and then on js I again encoded the array

```
       <?php 
          $this->load->module('sim/sim');
          $enumList = $this->sim->status_enum_dropdown();
      ?>  

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var enumList = <?php echo json_encode($enumList); ?>;
        </script>
```

Now it works as expected.